# Mathematica Not finding Eigenvectors?

Tags: matrix, evaluation, linear-algebra

I have the following matrix:

mat =

{{-60., 0., 2.1*10^-35 II + 2.1*10^-35 (-1. II + Istar), 
  2.1*10^-35 II + 
   2.1*10^-35 (-1. II - 4.7619*10^6/Istar)}, {-6.4*10^22 II - 
   6.4*10^22 (-1. II - 4.7619*10^6/Istar), 0., 0., 
  0.}, {6.4*10^22 II + 
   6.4*10^22 (-1. II - 1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2]), 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., -((
    1.21485*10^17 (-3900. + 0.000625 II) II)/(1.2168*10^11 - 
      31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^2) + (
   1.21485*10^17 II (1.6731*10^8 - 58.5 II + 
      4.6875*10^-6 II^2) (-1. II - 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2]))/(1.2168*10^11 - 
     31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^3 - (
   2.91565*10^18 II (-1.77957*10^11 + 104569. II - 0.0182813 II^2 + 
      9.76563*10^-10 II^3) (-1. II - 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2])^2)/(1.2168*10^11 - 
     31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^4 + (
   9.71882*10^17 II (9.48511*10^15 - 8.89785*10^9 II + 2614.22 II^2 - 
      0.000304688 II^3 + 1.2207*10^-11 II^4) (-1. II - 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2])^3)/(1.2168*10^11 - 
     31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^5, 0., -156000.}}

(Apologies for how unwieldy it is)

When I run

```
Simplify@Eigenvectors[Rationalize[mat]]
```

I get the following output:

```
{{0., (156000. (1.2168*10^11 - 31200. II + 
   0.0025 II^2)^5)/(II (-1.18638*10^6 (-6.24*10^6 + 
      1. II) (4.8672*10^13 - 1.248*10^7 II + 1. II^2)^3 - 
   3.55914*10^6 (3.56928*10^13 - 1.248*10^7 II + 
      1. II^2) (4.8672*10^13 - 1.248*10^7 II + 
      1. II^2)^2 (1. II + 1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2]) - 
   7.11828*10^6 (4.8672*10^13 - 1.248*10^7 II + 
      1. II^2) (-1.82228*10^20 + 1.07078*10^14 II - 
      1.872*10^7 II^2 + 1. II^3) (1. II + 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2])^2 - 
   1.18638*10^7 (7.7702*10^26 - 7.28912*10^20 II + 
      2.14157*10^14 II^2 - 2.496*10^7 II^3 + 1. II^4) (1. II + 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2])^3)), 1.*10^-28/(
  0. + 2.1*10^-35 Istar^2), 1.}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0,
   0}}
```

This says that three of the eigenvectors are the zero vector, which is incorrect. Anyone know how to get Mathematica to find all of the eigenvectors?

Edit:

In addition, if I plug in values for II and Istar,

mat2 =

{{-60., 0., 2.1*10^-35 II + 2.1*10^-35 (-1. II + Istar), 
  2.1*10^-35 II + 
   2.1*10^-35 (-1. II - 4.7619*10^6/Istar)}, {-6.4*10^22 II - 
   6.4*10^22 (-1. II - 4.7619*10^6/Istar), 0., 0., 
  0.}, {6.4*10^22 II + 
   6.4*10^22 (-1. II - 1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2]), 0., 0., 
  0.}, {0., -((
    1.21485*10^17 (-3900. + 0.000625 II) II)/(1.2168*10^11 - 
      31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^2) + (
   1.21485*10^17 II (1.6731*10^8 - 58.5 II + 
      4.6875*10^-6 II^2) (-1. II - 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2]))/(1.2168*10^11 - 
     31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^3 - (
   2.91565*10^18 II (-1.77957*10^11 + 104569. II - 0.0182813 II^2 + 
      9.76563*10^-10 II^3) (-1. II - 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2])^2)/(1.2168*10^11 - 
     31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^4 + (
   9.71882*10^17 II (9.48511*10^15 - 8.89785*10^9 II + 2614.22 II^2 - 
      0.000304688 II^3 + 1.2207*10^-11 II^4) (-1. II - 
      1. Sqrt[1. - 2.26757*10^13/Istar^2])^3)/(1.2168*10^11 - 
     31200. II + 0.0025 II^2)^5, 0., -156000.}} /. {II -> 10^7 , Istar -> 10^7}

I get the following matrix:

```
{{-60., 0., 2.1*10^-28, -1.*10^-35}, {3.04762*10^22, 0., 0., 
  0.}, {-5.62779*10^22, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 1.40524*10^6, 0., -156000.}}
```

Whose eigenvectors are:

```
{{6.41272*10^-41, -1.25279*10^-23, 2.31343*10^-23, 
  1.}, {2.12771*10^-22, -0.108074, 
  0.199572, -0.973905}, {6.98757*10^-31, -0.108114, 
  0.199645, -0.973886}, {2.34186*10^-46, 0.110335, 4.73283*10^-8, 
  0.993894}}
```

So why doesn't Mathematica return the symbolic eigenvectors in the first case?

Comment: The presence of three zero vectors implies that your matrix is (apparently) *defective*. If need be, try `JordanDecomposition[]`.

Comment: When I use JordanDecomposition[] Mathematica just returns JordanDecomposition[mat].

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Try `Eigenvectors[Rationalize[mat, 0]]`.

Comment: Thanks, I've been having trouble with formatting.